# Pytest Flask post return 'Response' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, flask, pytest

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and Falsk, in which I'm implementing testing for my API. For a POST request, when I submit the request client using `test_client` with the proper payload it returns an error as:

> **AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'items'**

Here's what I have done so far:

**From `view function:`**

```
if request.method == "POST":
    data = request.get_json()
    new_author = data['author']
    new_title = data["title"]
    new_sDescription = data["shortDescription"]
    new_Url = data["thumbnailUrl"]
    new_status = data["status"]
    new_pageCount = data["pageCount"]
    ....
    if None not in (new_author, new_title, new_Url, new_status, new_pageCount
                    , new_sDescription):
        return f"Book with the id: {cursor.lastrowid} created successfully", 201
```

** Test Fixture:**

```
@pytest.fixture
def client():
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    db_fd, app.config['DATABASE'] = tempfile.mkstemp()

    with app.test_client() as client:
        with app.app_context():
            create_table(app.config['DATABASE'])
            yield client
```

** Function to send request:**

```
def api_post_book(client):
    payload = {
        "author": "Someone",
        "pageCount": 590,
        "shortDescription": "A book from PyTest.",
        "status": "PUBLISH",
        "thumbnailUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/AKIAJC5RLADLUMVRPFDQ.book-thumb-images/adzic.jpg",
        "title": "PyTest is a Fun."
    }
    return client.post('/api',
                       data=jsonify(payload), follow_redirects=True)
```

** Function to test: **

```
def test_api_post_book(client):
    resp = api_post_book(client)
    assert resp.status_code == 201
```

If I remove `jsonify` it returns another error as:

> **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable**

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
return client.post('/api', json=payload, follow_redirects=True)
```

Or if you absolutely want to use jsonify, use:

```py
return client.post('/api', json=jsonify(payload).get_json(), follow_redirects=True)
```

You need to keep in mind that jsonify returns a `Response` object and not json.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question that I tried it by removing `jsonify` and in this case it returns another error and pointing where I'm parsing the JSON data as `new_author = data['author']`. As per the view response, I have tested it it's returned the response.

Comment: Yes, it was the wrong parameter name. Sorry for the confusion. I edited my answer accordingly.